# "mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable" error

Tags: openmpi

I came across a strage problem, which worked but now it doesn't.

I run an OpenMPI program with tau profiling among 2 computers. It seems that mpirun can't run tau_exec program on a remote host, maybe it's a permission issue?

```
 cluster@master:~/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2$ mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile -d           tau_exec -v -T MPI,TRACE,PROFILE ./hello.exe
 [master:19319] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cluster@master_0/4568/0/0
 [master:19319] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cluster@master_0/4568/0
 [master:19319] top: openmpi-sessions-cluster@master_0
 [master:19319] tmp: /tmp
 [slave2:06777] procdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cluster@slave2_0/4568/0/1
 [slave2:06777] jobdir: /tmp/openmpi-sessions-cluster@slave2_0/4568/0
 [slave2:06777] top: openmpi-sessions-cluster@slave2_0
 [slave2:06777] tmp: /tmp
 [master:19319] [[4568,0],0] node[0].name master daemon 0 arch ff000200
 [master:19319] [[4568,0],0] node[1].name slave2 daemon 1 arch ff000200
 [slave2:06777] [[4568,0],1] node[0].name master daemon 0 arch ff000200
 [slave2:06777] [[4568,0],1] node[1].name slave2 daemon 1 arch ff000200
 [master:19319] Info: Setting up debugger process table for applications
   MPIR_being_debugged = 0
   MPIR_debug_state = 1
   MPIR_partial_attach_ok = 1
   MPIR_i_am_starter = 0
   MPIR_proctable_size = 2
   MPIR_proctable:
     (i, host, exe, pid) = (0, master,      /home/cluster/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2/tau_exec, 19321)
     (i, host, exe, pid) = (1, slave2,      /home/cluster/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2/tau_exec, 0)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

 Executable: tau_exec
 Node: slave2

 while attempting to start process rank 1.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [slave2:06777] sess_dir_finalize: job session dir not empty - leaving
 [slave2:06777] sess_dir_finalize: job session dir not empty - leaving
 [master:19319] sess_dir_finalize: job session dir not empty - leaving
 [master:19319] sess_dir_finalize: proc session dir not empty - leaving
 orterun: exiting with status -123
```

On slave2:

```
cluster@slave2:~/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2$ tau_exec -T MPI,TRACE,PROFILE ./hello.exe
hello MPI user: from process = 0 on machine=slave2, of NCPU=1 processes
cluster@slave2:~/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2$ which tau_exec
/home/cluster/tools/tau-2.22.2/arm_linux/bin/tau_exec
```

So there is a working tau_exec on both nodes. When I run mpirun without tau_exec everything works.

```
cluster@master:~/software/mpi_in_30_source/test2$ mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile  ./hello.exe
hello MPI user: from process = 0 on machine=master, of NCPU=2 processes
hello MPI user: from process = 1 on machine=slave2, of NCPU=2 processes
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the full path to `tau_exec` in your command line. It's possible that you PATH isn't the same on all of the nodes. If that's the case, it wouldn't be able to find the executable anywhere where the path isn't correct.

It's most likely not a permission issue, but I don't remember all of the error messages in Open MPI to tell you how helpful they might be.

Comment: This can actually be an issue even on a simple laptop: somehow OpenMPI did not liked `~` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

once had an error like this when i tried to name the output file
just try leave it the same

```
    mpirun -n <number> a.out
```

that is how it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is because you already had installed openMPI and not only MPICH2, so you should run the below commands as root:

*root~#* **update-alternatives --config mpirun**

*There are 2 choices for the alternative mpirun (providing /usr/bin/mpirun).*

*Selection |   Path    |                 Priority |  Status*

- *0       |     /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi  | 50  |      auto mode
- 1       |     /usr/bin/mpirun.mpich2   | 40  |      manual mode
- 2       |     /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi  | 50  |      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: **1**

Then you should select the **MPICH** version, as above, to run normally.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a shell script with mpirun, make sure you've `chmod +x script_file.sh` else you'll see this error.